# How to get a specific string from a path?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to make an automatic backup script, that I wil run on 30 differents computers.
For example if the path is C:\Users\PC1, then I want to copy all the files from PC1 (C:\Users\PC1) to C:\Backup\PC1, from PC2 to C:\Backup\PC2 and so on.  So I have to ask the path of the computer, get the name of it and put that name in the path where I want to save the copy. I know I have to use robocopy to make the backup but I don't know how to get the name of the pc from the path

Comment: If the backup script runs on each computer (as you wrote), then you are able to use `$env:computername` to retrieve the computer name. You don't have to parse a path...

Comment: Thnx I think that will work. But if I need the name of a specific map in the path and not the name of the PC, for example C:\myexamplefiles\myfile\blXX\backup; XX going from 01 to 30, how can I get the numbers of blXX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the Computername using the `env`variable: `$env:Computername`

If you need to parse the path, you should use the [Split-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113404) cmdlet and / or regex. Here the solution of your question (comment) using regex:

```
 $path = 'C:\myexamplefiles\myfile\bl12\backup'

 # Pick one of these regex:
 $regex = '.*\\bl(..)' # this regex catches any two characters after bl
 $regex = '.*\\bl([^\\]*)' # this regex catches anything after bl until the next slash
 $regex = '.*\\bl(\d\d)' # this regex catches two digits after bl

 [regex]::Match($path, $regex).Groups[1].Value
 #OUTPUT:  12
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely what I was looking for!